# Generating lists in R with patterns related to the entry number

Tags: r, list

Is there a smart way to generate a list like the one below in R using perhaps `lapply()` or other more extrapolable procedures?

```
ones   =   c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
twos   =   c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)
threes =   c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0)
fours  =   c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
fives  =   c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
l = list(ones, twos, threes, fours)

[[1]]
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

[[2]]
 [1] 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1

[[3]]
 [1] 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0

[[4]]
 [1] 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0
```

These correspond to polynomials coefficients in generating functions for partitions.

The first list is for `ones` and so the counting is in steps of `1` integer at a time; hence the vector `1,1,1,1,1,1,1,...` In the entry `[[2]]` we have the `twos`, and we are counting by `2`'s starting at `0`, skipping the `1` (coded as `0`). In `[[3]]` we are counting by `3`'s: zero, three, six, nine, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A fairly straightforward way in base R is

```
lapply(seq(0L, 5L), function(i) rep(c(1L, integer(i)), length.out=11L))
[[1]]
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

[[2]]
 [1] 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1

[[3]]
 [1] 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0

[[4]]
 [1] 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0

[[5]]
 [1] 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1
```

- `seq(0L, 5L)` produces the vector 0 through 5, an equivalent would be `seq_len(5L)-1L`, which is faster for creation of large vectors.
- `c(1L, integer(i))` produces the inner, repeated part of the 0-1 vectors, which `rep` repeats according to the desired length (here 11) using the length.out argument.
- `lapply` and `function(i)` allow the number of 0s to increase as we loop through the vector.